# How to separate access to remoteapp and remote desktop for same user on different computers?

Tags: windows, domain-controller, rdp

I have a:

- WS2012 Domain Controller.
- Windows 10 Workstation.
- Terminal Server RDP  2012.
- Domain user.

In my case I need to deny access to RDP server via RDP, and allow remoteapp. For Windows 10, sometimes need to not connect local but via remote RDP.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [Permissions for RemoteApp but not RemoteDesktop](https://serverfault.com/questions/422381/permissions-for-remoteapp-but-not-remotedesktop):

> Short Answer: No.
>
> Long Answer:
>
> RemoteApp utilizes the remote desktop protocol and actually runs a
>   complete remote desktop session whenever a user opens RemoteApp it
>   just hides the full desktop and provides a container that the
>   application runs within. So technically by using RemoteApp you are
>   using Remote Desktop.
>
> If you truly want a virtualized or remotely hosted application you are
>   looking into the wrong technology. You really want to investigate
>   App-V. It's a more expensive technology and came out of a company
>   Microsoft bought a couple of years ago. Essentially with this
>   technology the application is streamed to the client as bits and
>   pieces are needed. There are also other options like the offerings
>   Citrix provides as well.
>
> Hope that helps.
>
> Edit:
>
> After a quick search it looks like there may also be some freeware
>   available to accomplish this. However a lot of people simply have
>   login tasks that call logoff.exe. So when a user tries to use remote
>   desktop it simply makes a call to immediately log them off. Kinda
>   hacky but it appears to work.

Comment: I understand that remoteapp is just a part of RDP. I found solution like using logoff.exe, but the problem how to use it only to the RDP Server, not on workstation. Because one person that domain user can work via remoteapp on RDP Server, but can be situation when he work from home connecting to his workstation via RDP, for example. Maybe exist some local politics to resolve this problem?
About App-V, dont know about it before, so I will need time learn this technology

Comment: use related GPO or local policies only for RDP server

Comment: And what exactly GPO should use?

Comment: Question is still actual. I cant find guide to solve this with GPO.